# Ошибка The local repository is out of date. GitHub XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, github, swift3

Я привязал в гитхабе себя и еще одного программиста создав новую организацию. 
В ней я создал Responsitory и привязал опять его. 
Он залил проект в гит хаб , я его скачал и исправил , сделав комит . Когда нажал на push он мне выдает ошибку: 
***The local repository is out of date.
Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again.***
После этого я нажал на Refresh status и потом pull , где написано что нет ных remotes.

Я читал многое , что надо заново проект создать , я его не менее 10 раз пересоздавал , потом что надо дописать что то в терминале. Но ничего не помогает.

Может кто нибудь помочь ?

Comment: в терминале `git clone <ссылка на репозиторий>` и с ним уже пробуйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была такая же проблема. Только я пытался отправить  свой проект на GitHub с созданным там gitignor'ом и readme.txt чего не нужно было делать. Уберите их и попробуйте заново. Если все так же не получается, то вам нужно локально инициализировать ваши документы.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка возникает в случае когда ваш коммит вы создали не локально, а сразу на серваке, для решения надо вытянуть это изменеие с сервака и заливать проект.

Что нажимать?

`Source controll -> Pull`
ждем пока вытянет 
`Source controll -> Push`